# SQL Query - Adding total amounts from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I'm working on a project for a client and require the total sum of 3 different columns on 3 different tables where the status of these amounts is stated as "Cleared".

The three tables are (as an example):

**PAYMENT1**

```
ID | Amount | Status  
1  | 200    | Cleared
```

**PAYMENT2**

```
ID | Amount | Status              
1  | 100    | Cleared
```

**PAYMENT3**

```
ID | Amount | Status  
1  | 300    | Cleared
```

I have come up with the following code which does essentially what I want to achieve but the values that are getting processed are coming out being multiplied by three (when adding values from more than one table).

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN P1.`Status` = "Cleared" THEN P1.Amount ELSE 0 END) 
     + SUM(CASE WHEN P2.`Status` = "Cleared" THEN P2.Amount ELSE 0 END)
     + SUM(CASE WHEN P3.`Status` = "Cleared" THEN P3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS ClearedFunds
FROM PAYMENT1 As P1, 
     PAYMENT2 As P2, 
     PAYMENT3 As P3 ;
```

The query above would return (from the examples given): 1800 instead of the expected result of 600.

Can anyone find out what is going wrong?

Comment: There's no join criteria, so you're getting a cartesian product.  Hence, the results being 3x what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply OMG Ponies. What would be required to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ID, SUM(Amount) totalAmount
FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, Amount
        FROM    payment1
        WHERE   Status = 'Cleared'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID, Amount
        FROM    payment2
        WHERE   Status = 'Cleared'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID, Amount
        FROM    payment3
        WHERE   Status = 'Cleared'
    ) s
GROUP   BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union all with three select queries to get the result as a single table and then use sum aggregate function to get the sum of amount where status is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ravi. Would you be able to provide an example of this using SQL code as I am still quite unsure.

Comment: When you execute this query: SELECT * FROM payment1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM payment2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM payment3 you will get the output like this: id amount status
1 200 Cleared
1 100 Cleared
1 300     Cleared Now you can use this as the table to get sum

Comment: @steve Here is the exact query: select sum(p4.amount) from (SELECT p1.amount FROM payment1 as p1
UNION
SELECT p2.amount FROM payment2 as p2
UNION
SELECT p3.amount FROM payment3 as p3) as p4 where p4.status = 'Cleared'